# AspxGridView , How to prevent updating when update button is clicked?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a list of data in aspxgridview and it contains 3 check columns "Yes", "No", "Not Exist"

if one of them is checked, Editing should be allowed, otherwise it shouldn't be allowed.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I found an answer to this question.

[Devexpress support](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T263022)

[Video](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Attachment/GetAttachmentFile/ad115792-2193-11e5-80bf-00155d62480c)